# How to save a form's 'file' input to disk?

Tags: php, html

I have never done anything of this sort and I can't seam to find a decent tutorial to teach me how to do this...

I have an html form as follow:

```
<form class = "form-course-setup" id="form-course-add" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="syllabus" size="40"> 
</form>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form-course-add').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get('../php/lecturer_addcourse.php',$(this).serialize(),
        function(data){
            if(data == true)
            {
               ...  
            }
});
```

in lecturer_addcourse.php

I would want to save the syllabus attachment to remote server (to be downloaded later on)...

How can I do that?

PS: If this not stack overflow type of questions please let me know and I would gladly delete this post :)

Answer (score 1):

Due to outdated security models, browsers never allowed javascript to read files. The latest browsers can do now it, but only via the FileReader API. If you want to do this yourself it will be days lf work. Or you can find a third party library such as "FineUploader".

Much easier is just to remove your javascript completely and do `<form action="../php/lecturer_addcourse.php" ...>`

Also, make sure your php script does not allow anyone to upload php scripts. A lot of servers get hacked by making that mistake.

Comment: Unfortuantely I need to use js as I am doing many client side actions with the form submit

Comment: then you should look into "FineUploader"